# Got 404 when running quarkus "code-with-quarkus" app in dev mode

Tags: quarkus

I followed the instructions on https://quarkus.io/get-started/ and build this demo using the latest quarkus(2.7).
My java environment is:
[image: my java enviornment]

when I run `quarkus dev` it turns out fine like this:
[image: quarkus dev]

But when I access http://localhost:8080/hello I got an 404 like this:
[image: 404 not found]

I should have got a string "Hello RESTEasy" as the demo code is like:
[image: demo code]

Can any one tell me why would this happen?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem

Comment: thank you anyway. BTW can you post your java environment?

Comment: It should not make a difference, but I am using Java 11 and Ubuntu Linux

Comment: you're right. I solved this by restart my os anyway...